# Android doesn't receive push notifications from new Parse Server

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, parse-server

I'm migrating my Android and iOS apps from parse.com to Parse Server (by the way I'm using a Parse test app but I guess it's not relevant to this issue). After the migration, everything is working well but the push notifications to Android device (they are working well to my iOS app).

This is what I've done so far.

**1. In my Parse Server** code (on Digital Ocean by the way), in /home/parse/index.js I've initialized Parse Server this way:

```
var api = new ParseServer({  
  databaseURI: databaseUri || '<my mongodb url>',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || '<my app ID>',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '<my master Key>',
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',
  push: {
    android: {
        senderId: '<my GCM sender Id>',
        apiKey: '<my GCM API Key>'
      },
    ios: [{
      pfx: '/home/parse/<my dev P12>',  
      passphrase: '',
      cert: '',
      key: '',
      bundleId: '<my bundle ID>',
      production: false
    },
    {
      pfx: '/home/parse/<my prod P12>',  
      passphrase: '',
      cert: '',
      key: '',
      bundleId: '<my bundle ID>',
      production: true
    }]
  }
});
```

I’ve taken "my GCM sender ID" from my Google Developer Consoler, it’s the 12 digits number from Settings > Project number.

I’ve tried with 3 different "my GCM API Key", one without app restrictions, one available only for my android/debug.keystore and one available only for my app keystore.

I’ve checked that I have selected this app in my Google Developer console and that my package id is correct in all places.

**2.** Once I’ve made this change I’ve **restarted Parse Server** with

```
pm2 delete all // this with parse user
pm2 start ecosystem.json // this with parse user
pm2 save // this with parse user
sudo service nginx restart //this with my sudo user
```

**3. In Android** I’m initializing Parse this way:

```
public static void initParse(Application app) {
    ctxt = app.getApplicationContext();
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(app);
    // Old version
    Parse.initialize(app, "<my app id>", "<my client key>");
    // New version
    //Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(ctxt)
    //        .applicationId("<my app id>")
    //        .clientKey(null)
    //        .server("https://<my new server>/parse/")
    //        .build()
    //);
    ParseUser.enableRevocableSessionInBackground();
}
```

I’m not initializing with the new method because it’s crashing (this is the issue of another question [Android switch from Parse to Parse Server crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40767094/android-switch-from-parse-to-parse-server-crashes)), but I guess this initialization doesn’t affect the push notifications.

**4. In Android** I’ve added this to my Android Manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id"
                   android:value="id:<my GCM sender Id>" />;
```

The rest of my manifest and my GCM configuration is the same I had before the migration.

**5. And as a summary**.

With old parse.com push notifications worked well with Android and iOS.

With new Parse Server and the code described above iOS push notifications are working well.

With new Parse Server and the code described above Android push notifications are not being received.

With my new Parse Dashboard installed in Digital Ocean when sending push notifications both to iOS and to Android Dashboard gives a Saved! what makes me thing it’s a problem with my Android app and not with my Parse Dashboard/Parse Server configuration.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you trigger the push from the client or from cloud code?

Comment: I trigger the push from the new Parse Dashboard (from its Push section). This Parse Dashboard is installed together with Parse Server in my Digital Ocean server.

Comment: Can you share some logs?

Comment: Sure, as soon as I can, I'll try to get these logs and share them. But, I'm not sure if there will be logs because in Parse Dashboard I get a "Saved!" after sending the notification, and it has been sent ok (it arrives at my iOS device). And in my Android device I haven't been able to see any log related to notifications, it's like no notification has been received.

Comment: As I was afraid, I can't find any log. In my Android app there is no logs (with app in foreground and with app in background) when I send the push form the dashboard. Regarding to the Parse Server and the Parse Dashboard, I don't know where are the logs (dashboard has a log tab but it's empty), and in the system /var/log has no file related to Parse. I've read the Parse docs and I don't know where to find the logs.

Comment: Possible issue: You can only send push notifications to those Android users that have updated your app with the new GCM Sender Id (post migration). If your setup is correct, you should be able to send a push notification to any of the devices in the [Installation] table that contain your GCM Sender ID in the GCMSenderId column. If this column is blank, you cannot send to these device as that GCM Sender ID belongs to Parse. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38389328/5121567 related to SNS but still relevant here.

Comment: I think this is the problem, the field GCMSenderId is empty for all my Android users. But they are updated to the new version of my app. This version includes the com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id in the Manifest. I've added ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground(); just after the Parse.initialize but if I check again the CGMSenderId field it's empty yet. Why?

Comment: And one thing more, if I set manually  in the Parse database the GCMSenderId to the correct sender Id the push is not received yet (?!)

Answer (score 0):

you can try using "**CURL**" to specified only "**android**" device.

```
curl -X POST \
    -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: you_app_id" \
    -H "X-Parse-Master-Key: your_master_key" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{
          "where": {
            "deviceType": {
              "$in": [
                "android"
              ]
            }
          },
          "data": {
            "title": "The Shining",
            "alert": "All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy."
          }
        }'\   http://your_server_address/parse/push
```

Then you can find out the exactly what is wrong.

Comment: This returns {"result":true} but the push is not received. In think the problem is what Dennis AWS told in the comments of my question: GCMSenderId is empty in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Parse SDK libraries are updated!

I was having a bunch of trouble getting Android notifications pushed from Parse Dashboard too, but it was all resolved when I updated my libraries to Parse 1.13.0 and Bolts 1.4.0.